# Remove brackets [] from list (while sorting with key)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What i am after:** instead of having a list output like this:
`['test1', 'test2', test3']`

i would want it to output like this:
`test1 | test2 | test3` or this is fine too `test1, test2, test3`

**My code:** right now this is how it looks like:

```
deelnemers = []
# i add name, csgo and score to deelnemers[] via class Deelnemer
    deelnemers.append(Deelnemer(naam, int(csgo), int(score)))

    # key to sort it by csgo value
    def keyCSGO(deelnemer):
            return deelnemer.csgo

    # i print it in reverse so the highest csgo number will be first
    print("\nNaam | CSGO Score\n----------------\n", sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True))
```

**What i have tried:**

```
print(", ".join("\nNaam | CSGO Score\n----------------\n", sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True)))
```

so obviously the above gives that you can have only 1 argument with .join: `join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

so i removed the naam | csgo part to test it out:

```
print(", ".join(sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True)))
```

but now i get this exception: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, Deelnemer found`

i think i am looking in the wrong direction, so i am not sure where to look at to have [ '' ] removed from a list. Thank you for the help and advice.

Comment: Side-note: You don't need to write your own function for simple attribute lookup. `from operator import attrgetter`, then replace `key=keyCSGO` with `key=attrgetter('csgo')`. Pushes more work to the C layer, more flexible (to sort by a second field, just make it `attrgetter('csgo', 'secondattrname')`) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only *join* strings, so you probably need to access the `name` attribute (assuming that what it is) of each instance after sorting to use them in `join`:

```
print(", ".join(d.name for d in sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True)))
```

You can also put the attributes in a string before joining using *string formatting* (credits @Tadhg):

```
", ".join("{0.name} {0.csgo} {0.score}".format(d) for d in sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True))
```

Comment: using only the information in the question you can't even be sure that the `Deelnemer` objects have a `.name` attribute, it may be more useful to just state that the logic to get a string representation for each object would go where you currently have `d.name`. The most obvious solution to me would be `str(d)`.

Comment: is it possible to have more strings like d.name? lets say i want d.name, d.csgo. so instead of just 1 attribute i give 2 or 3. what i mean is like this: `print(", ".join(d.name, d.csgo, d.score for d in sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True)))`

Comment: @FatalRein dealing with strings is not the same as using the print function, the print function turns everything to strings for you and adds the seperators, if you want to handle that part yourself you would need to do something like `", ".join("{0.name} {0.csgo} {0.score}".format(d) for d in sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True))`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks for noting that.

Comment: guys, i can't thank you enough. that last part did it :) {0.xx} thank you so much to all of you who helped me out

Answer (score 2):

`str.join` can only join strings. Hopefully the `Deelnemer` class has a `__str__` method defined, then you can do:

```
print("Naam | CSGO Score\n----------------")
print(", ".join(map(str, sorted(deelnemers, key=keyCSGO, reverse=True))))
```

Comment: so, my class has a __ init __ and __ repr __ defined. i just add __ str __ with the name, csgo, score attributes? sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: It depends what you want listed in the table. The name? Then you can do what Moses Koledoye proposes, or make `__str__` return `self.name`. Something else? Then return that, just make sure it's a string that's being returned.

Comment: i want to return name, csgo or name | csgo (something like this)

Comment: If that's what you want to print, have `__str__` return `self.name`, as I said, or copy the solution from the other answer in case that is easier to understand.

Comment: if you want the two print statements to go to the same line remember to add `end=""` to the first call !

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I removed a trailing `\n` from the original string, so I don't think that will be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to using `str.join` is to let `print` do more of the work for you; it's happy to stringify and insert separators:

```
from operator import attrgetter

# Print header normally, but let print handle the newlines and separate lines
# so alignment of header and bar more obvious
# You original code was one hyphen short (which I fixed)
print("Naam | CSGO Score",
      "-----------------", sep="\n")

# Use *-unpacking to convert sorted list to sequential positional arguments
# and pass sep=', ' to replace default sep of ' '.
# Use attrgetter instead of rolling your own key function
print(*sorted(deelnemers, key=attrgetter('csgo'), reverse=True), sep=', ')
```